# In kotlin for a lateinit why it has to use "this::"

Tags: kotlin-lateinit

The [doc](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew12.html#lateinit-top-level-properties-and-local-variables) shows sample for checking whether a lateinit var has been initialized:

```
println("isInitialized before assignment: " + this::lateinitVar.isInitialized)
lateinitVar = "value"
println("isInitialized after assignment: " + this::lateinitVar.isInitialized)
```

Why it has to use the "this::" as its qualifier

Answer (score 1):

The answer lays in decompiled bytecode. When you call `lateinitVar` you access field with initialization check:

```
println("logProperty: " + lateinitVar)
```

is compiled to:

```
StringBuilder var10000 = (new StringBuilder()).append("logProperty: ");
String var10001 = this.lateinitVar;
if (this.lateinitVar == null) {
   Intrinsics.throwUninitializedPropertyAccessException("lateinitVar");
}
String var1 = var10000.append(var10001).toString();
System.out.println(var1);
```

but this:

```
println("logProperty: " + this::lateinitVar.isInitialized)
```

is compiled to:

```
String var1 = "logProperty: " + (((MyClass)this).lateinitVar != null);
System.out.println(var1);
```